# dispatch_async doesn't fire until returned parent thread returns?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

My Question is - Does dispatch_async fire immediately? I'm seeing that the creating thread has to return before dispatch_async fires.

My issue is that I am trying to make a async call to a 3rd party library appear to be synchronous. I know, I know... I should allow these async operations run as intended but I'm trying to do this way down in a complex multi-threaded operation and I really don't have a choice.

here's what starts the async call

```
-(void)connect
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0) , ^{
        [device connect];
    });

    while(!connectCompleted)
    {
        NSLog(@"Sleeping..");
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
    }
}
```

and here's the delegate function that gets called AFTER the [device connect] successfully connects:

```
- (void)didConnect:(BXPrinterController *)controller
printer:(BXPrinter *)printer
{
    connectCompleted = YES;

    NSLog(@"didConnect");
}
```

with that dispatch_async wrapped around [device connect] the delegate never gets fired;

Comment: Do not do this if you are not sure that the library will call the delegate on the main queue

Comment: to answer my own question... dispatch_async DOES fire immediately when you use the high priority.  I put some logging in place to test this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for whatever reason you must make a call appear synchronous, I'd recommend that you first implement it synchronously (because you'll end up doing that anyway if people had enough of delays), and then you write a helper method that is synchronous:

```
Step 1: Create a dispatch_semaphore_t. 
Step 2: Start the asynchronous code, with every code path ending by sending a signal to the dispatch_semaphore_t. 
Step 3: Send a wait to the dispatch_semaphore_t. It wakes up, with no CPU time spent on it at all, just when the asynchronous code finishes.
```

Comment: using semaphores seemed to have worked!  it looks like my other issue was that the async call was firing and then the delegate fired after [device connect] runs did not know who to return to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Does dispatch_async fire immediately

Of course not! That is what `async` *means*! The whole basis of the concept "asynchronous" (which is what `async` stands for) is that this is code that runs at some future unspecified time. Meanwhile the code that *calls* `dispatch_async` continues on to its end without waiting.